# Trying to set backgroundColor using a variable but does not work. Why?

Tags: javascript

In the following code, I am trying to set `backgroundColor` via a variable `prop`. I would like to know the reason as to why `div.style.prop` does not work.

```
var div = document.getElementById('test')

var prop = 'backgroundColor'
div.innerHTML = 'This is some text'

div.style.prop = 'red'
```

Comment: `div.style[prop] = 'red'`

Comment: your `var prop` has nothing to do with `div.style.prop`, they are two different variables. `div.style.prop` doesn't exist either, unless you create it (which is pointless). Do as the above comment suggests.